# C# follow folder junctions with FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher, junction

Is it possible to configure a `FileSystemWatcher` to watch other folders which are linked in with a folder junction point?

for example:

You are watching D:

You have D:\junction which points to E:\folder

When I create a file in E:\folder\file.txt I want to see it with the watcher as D:\junction\file.txt.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`FileSystemWatcher` is not supposed to monitor junctions or symlinks... and it monitors one folder at a time.

Comment: "monitors one folder at a time"... yes, but you can configure to also watch subfolders. junctions in subfolders seems to be not resolved by filesystemwatcher... :-(

Answer (score 2):

Although Junctions are not supported, I believe Hard Links are:

- http://qualapps.blogspot.com/2010/05/understanding-readdirectorychangesw_19.html
- http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fsutil_hardlink.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Yes Hardlinks must be supported since every normal file is nothing else than a hard link. The other thing is that hardlinks are for files and junctions for folders. I have links between folders so I use junctions. thx anyway

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to setup FileSystemWatcher for each subfolder including junction points.

```
private static void SetupFileSystemWatchers(string path, FileSystemEventHandler changedEventHandler)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) && Directory.Exists(path))
  {
    var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path);
    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
    watcher.Changed += changedEventHandler;
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    foreach (var subDirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {
      SetupFileSystemWatchers(subDirectory, changedEventHandler);
    }
  }
```